# "Flag" / Report user functionality to work — Swift / Xcode / Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to allow a user to report a user (in a Tinder-like app). To report, this button takes the user to a new VC to elaborate the issue as an email.

**What I'm missing:**
How can I add the reporter's and reportee's Firebase unique ID to the email (or whatever form of communication)? (So then I can investigate and take action as needed)

**Here's what I have:**
The code to properly send an email...

```
 func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["RadiusAppHelp@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Reporting user")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Please include as much detail as possible:", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}

func showMailError() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = showAlert(withTitle: "Could not send message", message: "Please try again")
    let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil)
 //        sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
 //        self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

The code to pull the other user's ID in the swipe view VC...

```
 var otherUsersId = ""
 var currentlyViewedUserId: String?

firebaseServer.fetchUsers {[weak self] (usersDict) in
        self?.usersDict = usersDict
        let fetchedUsers = Array(usersDict.values)
        self?.filterBlockedUsers(from: fetchedUsers)
        self?.loadFirstUser()
        self?.cardView.reloadData()
    }

  func loadFirstUser() {
    if users.count > 0 {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(withPath: 
  "\(users[0].userId!)/photos/\(0)")
        currentlyViewedUserId = users[0].userId
        PhotoUploader.downloadImageUrl(from: 
  storageRef) { (url) in
            guard let url = url else { return }
            imageView.downloaded(from: url, 
  contentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
        }
        nameLbl.text = users[0].firstName
        setupDetailsFor(user: users[0])
        infoCollectionView.reloadData()
       }
  }
```

As well as the code to block a user (but blocking / reporting functions work independently).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why handle this through email? Keep both your data and your operations encapsulated. Why not record the report in the database? You can keep a running count of reports against a user that you can query against and that can invoke a cloud function when a threshold is passed.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even think of this. Can you tell me how this would be structured? I would prefer to do that instead of email.

Comment: For internal purposes, all you need to do is increment an integer value in some document tied to the reported user every time they're reported. You can construct a simple cloud function that notifies you (or even suspends or deletes the user) when that number gets to a certain point.

Comment: For UX purposes, if you don't want these users to see each other after the report, you could create a document that records the userId of the reporter and the userId of the reported. Then query for these documents where the reporter is the current userId and construct an array of the reported userIds. Then wherever you render user profiles, make sure none of those profiles are in this array of reported users. Additionally, you could query for documents where the current user is the reported, so not only are the reported hidden from the reporters but the reporters are hidden from the reported.

Comment: Okay awesome, I think I see how that would work then. Thank you for your help! I'll start digging into this.

Comment: You using Firestore or RTDB?

Comment: RTDB, which I'm now realizing it might be better to use Firestore because of the complexity applicable.

Comment: For what you're doing, definitely get on Firestore.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found at least a temporary fix... 
(Not using Firestore however, which I'll eventually need to implement — https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI)

In FirebaseFunctions.swift...

```
// Report Someone

func reportSomeone(with userId: String, completion: 
@escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let usersRef = db.child("users")

    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        usersRef.child("\(uid)/report/\ . 
 (userId)").setValue(true) { (error, dbref) in
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}

// Set Preferences for Reporting

   func reportPreferences(with userId: String, 
completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
   let usersRef = db.child("users")

       if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
           usersRef.child("\(uid)/preferences/\ . 
  (userId)").setValue(true) { (error, dbref) in
               completion(error)
           }
       }
   }
```

In User.swift...

```
var report: [String: Bool]? = [:]

func makeDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    print("")
    return [
"report": report ?? [:]
]

 static func makeObjectFrom(_ dictionary: [String: 
 Any]) -> LocalUser {
 let report = dictionary["report"] as?
        [String:Bool] ?? [:]
 }

let localUser = LocalUser(report: report)
```

In the View Controller...

```
import Firebase

var currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var otherUsersId = ""

// Report Button
var isCurrentUserReported = false
var isOtherUserReported = false

var currentlyViewedUserId: String?

// FILTER REPORTED USERS

func filterReportUsers(from users: [LocalUser]) {
    var notReportUsers = users
    var notReportUsersDict = self.usersDict
    var reportUsers = newUser.report ?? [:]
    if let currentUserId = 
 Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        reportUsers[currentUserId] = true
    }

    for (userId, report) in reportUsers ?? [:] {
        print("UserId...", userId)
        print("UserHere...", usersDict[userId])
        if let user = usersDict[userId] {
            notReportUsersDict.removeValue(forKey: 
userId)
        }
    }
    let notReport = Array(notReportUsersDict.values)
    self.users = notReport
}
```

This isn't perfect, but it works!